# Does Android Oreo Go support tethering?

Tags: 8.0-oreo, 8.1-oreo, wifi-tethering, android-go

I want to get a cheap Android Go phone for wifi-tethering purposes as the battery is acting up on the cheap Argos Bush Hero 5.5 V3 AC55SEDCV2 phone I  use for that purpose.

Does Android Oreo Go support tethering? Because it is supposed to be an Android 8.0 with reduced functionality I have to check before I commit.